# How to get panelconfirmation action on success in icefaces?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I want to get panelconfirmation success action for redirect to another page.

How to do in the icefaces panelconfirmation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can show `ice:panelPopup` as a (modal) confirmation dialog box to the user.

According to the user action you can redirect to next page or render it false.